# React-Redux/Rails: Record will not delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux

I am integrating a delete feature as part of the whole CRUD realm and I am not able to delete my a record/object when I click  Delete Recipe. This is using React-Redux and Rails btw.

This is an example of what my backend console is telling me when I try to delete my recipe/record/object on the front end:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Recipe with 'id'={:id=>"2"}):
  
app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:10:in `show'
Started GET "/recipes/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-01-19 21:22:51 -0600
Processing by RecipesController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Recipe Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:10:in `show'
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms | Allocations: 824)
```

So far here is my delete action(thunk):

```
export const deleteRecipe = (recipeId) =>{
    const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:10524`
    const RECIPES_URL =`${BASE_URL}/recipes`

    return (dispatch) => {
        
        fetch(`${RECIPES_URL}/${recipeId}`)
          .then(response =>{ return response.json()})
          .then(id => { return dispatch({ type: 'Delete_Recipe', id })});
         
          
      };
       
  }
```

Here is my reducer:

```
  case 'Delete_Recipe':
            return{
                recipes: state.recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.id !== action.payload)
            }
```

In my browser console I receive the following:

```
    
GET
    http://localhost:10524/recipes/1
Status404
Not Found
VersionHTTP/1.1
Transferred16.69 KB (16.37 KB size)
Referrer Policyno-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Note: Below here might not be very important but just in case. Primarily I wanted to show the flow of data down to my components in case the question comes up**

Here is where I imported the deleteRecipe action and mapped dispatch to props

```
class RecipesContainer extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getRecipes()
      }
    

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
               <RecipeInput postRecipes={this.props.postRecipes} /> 
               <RecipeList recipes={this.props.recipes} deleteRecipe={this.props.deleteRecipe}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

    

}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        recipes: state.recipes
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return{
    postRecipes: (recipe) => dispatch(postRecipes(recipe)),
    getRecipes: () => dispatch(getRecipes()),
    // getCategories: () => dispatch(getCategories())
    deleteRecipe: (id) => dispatch(deleteRecipe(id))
    }
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(RecipesContainer)
```

Here is my RecipeList component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Recipe from './Recipe.js'

class RecipeList extends Component {



render() {
   const { recipes } = this.props
   return (
    
      
    <div>
      
      {recipes.map(recipe =>  {return <Recipe recipe={recipe} {...recipe} deleteRecipe={this.props.deleteRecipe} key={recipe.id} />})}
    </div>
   )
    
  }
}

export default RecipeList;
```

And here is my Recipe Component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Recipe from './Recipe.js'

class RecipeList extends Component {



render() {
   const { recipes } = this.props
   return (
    
      
    <div>
      
      {recipes.map(recipe =>  {return <Recipe recipe={recipe} {...recipe} deleteRecipe={this.props.deleteRecipe} key={recipe.id} />})}
    </div>
   )
    
  }
}

export default RecipeList;
```

Who is able to point out my issue?

Comment: Your action does not have payload, you should change action.payload to action.id: `state.recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.id !== action.id)`.

Comment: That did not work unfortunately :-(

Comment: add DELETE method to your `fetch`, `fetch(`${RECIPES_URL}/${recipeId}`, { method: 'DELETE' })`

Comment: That led to a CORS issue, but checking right now

Comment: This should be it. I am having a cors issue but know how to proceed from there. Thank you

Comment: @Thanh you can submit your solution regarding adding delete method, it worked.

Comment: I submitted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error because of wrong HTTP method so request is not sent to correct action of Rails controller, delete request should use `DELETE` method, so fetch function should be:

```
fetch(${RECIPES_URL}/${recipeId}, { method: 'DELETE' })
```